# Vue.js: Assigning a click action inside another click event

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make an edit mode when clicking on an "Edit" button. The mode should create a Save-button, a Delete-button and maybe something more.

I'm using jQuery to create the buttons and I'm trying to assign events to them, but the event handler gets fired when I assign it.
I've read something about event propagation is the problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

Not only does it get triggered, when I try to click the new button, the event is not fired.

Here's an isolated example of my problem:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooxQXR

I've tried several methods of interupting the propagation, but nothing seems to work.

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would forget about jQuery in this situation - and in most situations when using Vue. Why not use a simple if/else block in the template, like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYpQgW).

```html
<div id="app">
  <button v-if="!editMode" class="first" @click.stop="clickEvent">First</button>
  <template v-else>
      <button class="save">Save</button>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </template>
</div>
```

```html
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickEvent(e) {
      this.editMode = true;
    }
  },
})
```

Adding other event handlers to the save/delete buttons should not be a problem then.